# Comparring a string with a manually added string

Tags: string, input, compare, string-comparison

If have been cracking my head over this for a week now:
We have an assignment, where we have 2 options in our program, with option 1, the program asks for a name and a date, and then it generates an email addressed to the give name, with that date.
The second option, we have to paste text in to program, and it will tell us if the 'template' from option 1 is used or not, and it gives you the name, and date.

my question is now: how do I compare the given string, with the manual input string and make that name, and date (could be 2nd of oktober, could be 10/02, could be sunday the 2nd, basically anything that isn't the same as the template) and still make it say the template matches?

I thought: cutting the strings up, comparing them, word for word, but then what? and how?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you show us some code of what you have tried so far so we can help you precisely where you are stuck on? I suggest you to read our about section : http://stackoverflow.com/about and help : http://stackoverflow.com/help You will understand that questions must be as precise as you could, if you want people to be able to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know what language you are programming in, I will give you some examples of what you ask in the languages I know.

Python(2.7):

```
x = raw_input('Manual String') // get user input, this can be replaced
y = 'this is a string: '+ str(x) // use Str incase of a number or other format of x.
if(y == 'this is a string: doubleo'):
    print "The strings are equal!"
```

C:
use this page:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm